# How to pop up a key board when click on textfield in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new in unity. Now I want to share with you my problem. 
I create a page where I draw a textfield and a button. I want to show keyboard when click on textfield and also when click on the button the keyboard will not be visible. Please give me some link.

Comment: There is a stack overflow kind of website for Unity3d. I would recommend searching there first: http://answers.unity3d.com

Comment: unity (without the 3d) is totally different from unity3d